# Looping through SharePoint 2013 using SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-variable

Any ideas on how I can Loop through list A to get/set variables, one being a list name. Then using those variables, loop through other lists on the site. Basically a nested loop.

Problem is I can't specify another list using the variable which is what I am trying to do.  The workflow is built on list A.

Comment: Is this workflow meant to be run when on a single list item? Also, does list A contain a lookup to other lists on the site?

Comment: Yes list A is a list of the other lists I need to loop through. I want to get the names of the lists that need to be updated from List A then loop through each one of those lists to make edits.

I have been looking at a couple of links as possible solution:
http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224 and 
http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013

But was hoping I could find someone who has done something like this.

Comment: Your first call will be to get the names of the lists. Something like `http://site/_api/_web/lists/GetByTitle('ListA')?$select=ListNameColumn`. I think your issue will be when you update the other lists. Since you can only use the "Update List Item" action if you know the list you are updating. You may have to make another web  service call with POST to make the necessary edits.

Comment: try [This](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201184/how-to-get-document-file-name-or-any-related-url-which-holds-file-document-name) Link hope it will be helpfull to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Call Web Service action in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows. In there you can get or post almost anything you want for the specified list.

Also multiple calls are possible with different lists. Be sure to set a own variable for each list.

Here two starting points:

1. [How to use call web service action in SharePoint2013
   workflow](https://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/how-to-use-call-web-service-action-in-sharepoint2013-workflow/)
2. [CALLING THE SHAREPOINT 2013 REST API FROM A
   SHAREPOINT DESIGNER WORKFLOW](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

If you need more help, please give us some more information, what you want to do exactly, maybe someone can give you more information.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is what I am finding as the recommended option. I will give this a shot.