# How to get Document/File Name (or any Related URL which holds file/Document Name) from Document library in SPD workflow which Uses RESP API's

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to get the file/document name from library using the REST API and Looping which iterates through all items in library I have tried same thing for a normal list ,there I can get the name of any item very easily but am stucked with document name from document library
I have followed [This](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013) article and that is fine for reading List Items,here I want to do same for  a document library.
I tried reading document using it's server relative URL but it is not giving me any reasult

Answer (score 2):

resolved the issue as per bellow snapp
[image]

output
[image]